# How did I cast more than one delete vote?

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-delete

I noticed that some questions had already reached the required 3 delete votes and still hadn't been removed.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/168305/backtrack5-r2-injection-test-failed
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/171046/is-libreoffice-suite-really-as-good-as-openoffice-suite

[image: Negative delete votes]

After the questions were eventually deleted, I noticed that I have managed to cast more than one delete vote on them. How did that actually happen?

[image: Question #1]
[image: Question #2]

Comment: So now you're sure it's *really* deleted.

Comment: That's not "way past it"! [Wait until you reach 28 close-votes!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/eeeek-how-does-this-question-have-28-and-growing-close-votes-without-being-c) (10k only, sorry)